# Is there any performance gain from using a nashorn script engine over dynamicly loaded jars for dynamic runtime code?

Tags: java, dynamic, nashorn

I just recently discovered the `ScriptEntine` API in java mostly due to reading about Nashorn being in the JDK8.

Because you are able to execute java code within Javascript using Nashorn, I am wondering if it would be more beneficial to load external code as Javascript using a Script Engine instead of loading classes from external jars.

What are the pros and cons of both options?

Comment: "more beneficial to load external code as Javascript using a Script Engine instead of loading classes from external jars" — you lost me. What?

Comment: Um, if in "execute java code within javascript" your "java code" refers to the "external jar", Nashorn would still have to load your jar. In that case, it's just an additional layer of complexity (and a huge WTF as @Seth points out).